Crystal Reports SP 33 ASP.NET Seguridad Integrada
Estoy usando Crystal Reports Runtime 33 en ASP.NET por primera vez, la  versión que utilizamos actualmente en producción es la 21. La conexión es con SQL Server y el código utilizado es el siguiente:
Dim cnnInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
With cnnInfo
 .ServerName = "(local)"
 .DatabaseName = "MYDB"
 .IntegratedSecurity = True
End With

Call SetDBLogonForReport(cnnInfo, fCR)
Call SetDBLogonForSubReport(cnnInfo, fCR)

El problema es que Crystal Reports siempre intenta conectarse a la base de datos utilizando la identidad del grupo de aplicaciones de IIS (NetworkService) en lugar del usuario suplantado. La suplantación de identidad no funciona.
Probando encontramos:
Del (sp33) a (sp26). La suplantación no funciona para el informe.
Pero la suplantación si funciona para reportes con Crystal Reports (sp25) y menores.
¿Alguien sabe por qué? ¿Qué necesito cambiar para que funcione la suplantación?

Te paso mi código en C# en el que sobreescribo la conexión:
 var ci = (ConnectionInfo)_rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Clone();
 ci.ServerName = "MyServerToConnect";
 ci.DatabaseName = "MyDatabaseName";
 ci.UserID = "MyDBUser";
 ci.Password = "MyDBPassword";
 ci.LogonProperties.LookupNameValuePair("Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB";
 foreach (Table table in _rptDoc.Database.Tables)
 {
     var tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
     tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = ci;
     table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
 }

 var newTable = (CommandTable)_rptDoc.ReportClientDocument.DataDefController.Database.Tables[0].Clone();
 newTable.CommandText = sqlScript;
 newTable.ConnectionInfo.Password = "MyDBPassword";
 _rptDoc.ReportClientDocument.DatabaseController.SetTableLocation(
 _rptDoc.ReportClientDocument.DataDefController.Database.Tables[0], newTable);

 var crSections = _rptDoc.ReportDefinition.Sections;
 foreach (Section crSection in crSections)
 {
     var crReportObjects = crSection.ReportObjects;

     foreach (ReportObject crReportObject in crReportObjects)
     {
         if (crReportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
         {
             var crSubReportObject = (SubreportObject)crReportObject;
             var crSubReportDocument = crSubReportObject.OpenSubreport(crSubReportObject.SubreportName);
             foreach (Table table in crSubReportDocument.Database.Tables)
             {
                 var tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                 tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = ci;
                 table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
             }
         }
     }
 }

RptDoc es un ReportDocument
